# Add hyphen automatically in text field but not able to edit the textfield (Phone number masking)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, phone-number, masking

Using the below code, I am able to add hyphen automatically, but not able to do editing in the textfield properly.

For example when I click to insert any number between the already entered numbers in the textfield, this will insert the number at the end of the textfield and further not delete that number properly. Can anyone help me out?

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
  {    
     if(textField == txtUserName)
     {
         if (range.location == 12)
         {
             return NO;
         }
         if (range.length == 0 && ![[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]   characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]])
         {
             return NO;
         }       
        if (range.length == 0 && (range.location == 3 || range.location == 7))
         {
             txtUserName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-  %@",txtUserName.text,string];
             return NO;
         }
         if (range.length == 1 &&(range.location==4 ||range.location ==7))      
         {
             range.location--;
             range.length = 2;
              txtUserName.text = [txtUserName.text  stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
             NSLog(@"Nisha..%@",txtUserName.text);
             return NO;
          }
    }   
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear??

Comment: What @Sujay said, we have no clue what your code is trying to accomplish.  Most specifically, where do you want the hyphen to appear and when do you want it to?  It's clear from your code you have conditions for that, but we have no clue what those are.

Comment: Hyphen is working correctly .. But when i am doing editing in the number that would not work. when i entered the number inside the number then it goes to the end. i want editing correction in my code.

Comment: But what are the "rules" of this re-formatting? Please state them clearly.

Comment: Suppose the user first time enters the number like 123-456-7890. After that he want to change the digit 4 with 7 then the 7 digit is not inserted at the proper place. And the limit of 10 digit number would be exceed . i want to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you use 3 text fields instead and put a '-' between them?

Comment: No i am using only one textfield

Comment: @NishaGupta: Can you please share your code zip, so that I can help you out with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will also work when we will do copy-paste text in `UITextField`.

> **Warning-** This code won't work with your ***keyboard's delete button***. Anyway you need only ***keyboard's backspace button*** because ***Mobile keypad's delete button work like keyboard's backspace button***

**Note-** use `tag` for  your `UITextField` instead of directly compare `textField` to your outlet

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //(textField == txtUserName)
    // don't compare with ID, use tag
    if(textField.tag == 0 ) 
    {
        NSString *text = textField.text;
        NSUInteger textLength = text.length;
        NSString *trimText = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
        NSUInteger trimTextLength = trimText.length;

        if (range.length == 0 && [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        if( string.length > 0 ) {
            NSString *replacedText = text;
            if(trimTextLength < 10) {
                NSInteger remainingNumbers = (10-trimTextLength);
                if(string.length > remainingNumbers) {
                    string = [string substringToIndex:remainingNumbers];
                }
                replacedText = [replacedText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            }
            NSString *trimReplacedText = [replacedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
            if( trimReplacedText.length > 3 ) {
                trimReplacedText = [trimReplacedText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3, 0) withString:@"-"];
            }
            if( trimReplacedText.length > 7 ) {
                trimReplacedText = [trimReplacedText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(7, 0) withString:@"-"];
            }
            textField.text = trimReplacedText;
            return NO;
        }
        bool flag = false;
        if (range.length == 1 &&(range.location == 4 || (range.location == 7 && (textLength-trimTextLength)== 1 && [text rangeOfString:@"-"].location == 7) || (range.location == 8 && (textLength-trimTextLength)== 2) ))
        {
            range.location--;
            range.length = 2;
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (range.length >= 1)
        {
            flag = true;
        }

        if(flag) {
            NSString *replacedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

            NSString *trimReplacedText = [replacedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
            if( trimReplacedText.length > 3 ) {
                trimReplacedText = [trimReplacedText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3, 0) withString:@"-"];
            }
            if( trimReplacedText.length > 7 ) {
                trimReplacedText = [trimReplacedText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(7, 0) withString:@"-"];
            }
            textField.text = trimReplacedText;
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @ Sujay ....Again i am not able to do editing in the number. This cant resolve my problem

Comment: What are you trying and how are you trying?

Comment: *"Suppose the user first time enters the number like 123-456-7890. After that he want to change the digit 4 with 7 then the 7 digit is not inserted at the proper place. And the limit of 10 digit number would be exceed . i want to solve this problem."*

This is what you want, right?

Comment: I am trying to edit the number once they written. like i first time i write "123-456-7890" moblie number. Next time i thought oohhh there is 0 in the place of 4. how can i able to edit that digit.

Comment: ya that was ohkiee and very fine what u did. But i want where the user starts the editing the number again he can edit what ever digits he wants not only restrict one digit. But the limit of the number wont be excced

Comment: are you editing with delete button or backspace button??

Comment: @NishaGupta, check the update code, I missed to change flag value here

Comment: @Sujay...Thanku So much Sujay. This woud be very helpul for me. Now it works Correctly. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @NishaGupta, updated code will also work when we will copy-paste text to `UITextField`

Comment: ,Ohkiee  Thanku :-) @Sujay

Comment: @NishaGupta madam, Marking an answer with a 'check mark' is expected StackOverflow behavior. If the provided answer does not meet your needs, then provide a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Observe the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`. The affected text field is stored in the object parameter of the notification.
2. check the text format of `notification.object.text` if needed insert hyphen

Comment: Can u give me a example to do this. How to implement what u said.

Answer (score 0):

Even this question is too old but in case you need help you can use VMaskTextField library

https://github.com/viniciusmo/VMaskTextField